# check width of image before convert it

Tags: find, conversion, imagemagick

I use the following script to convert all `jpg` and `png` images:

```
# absolute path to image folder
FOLDER="/home/*/public_html/"

# max width
WIDTH=1280

# max height
HEIGHT=720

#resize png or jpg to either height or width, keeps proportions using imagemagick
find ${FOLDER}  -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)    -exec convert \{} -verbose -resize $WIDTHx$HEIGHT\> \{} \;
```

but I was shocked today when I run

```
ls -l
```

and found all photos modified, data changed, big or not

```
 Oct 28 11:18 /home/photos/20210321/T161631305496ece25372fc18a9239da7911ac7c0dd056 (2).jpg
```

So I'm thinking about using an `if` condition to check the path of the image first, then if  WIDTH is greater than 1280px run `convert`. Else don't do anything.

---

update 2

I built this script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for  i in /root/d/*.jpg; do
  read -r w h <<< $(identify -format "%w %h" "$i")
  if [ $w -gt  1280 ]; then
    FOLDER="$i"
    WIDTH=1280
    HEIGHT=720
    find ${FOLDER}  -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)    -exec convert \{} -verbose -resize $WIDTHx$HEIGHT\> \{} \;
  fi
done
```

So I see `find` better `for` .

`for` didn't search all folder and subfolders.

---

update 3

```
WIDTH=1280
HEIGHT=720
find /home/sen/tes/  -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)   | while read img; do \
  anytopnm "$img" | pamfile | \
   perl -ane 'exit 1 if $F[3]>1280' || convert  "$img"    -verbose -resize "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}>"   "$img"; \
done
```

it's working good , but i get

```
jpegtopnm: WRITING PPM FILE
```

when no images `> 1280`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to add an actual question.

Comment: It's unclear if your question is about your original script (in which case the second half is irrelevant) or about cleaning up after your mistake (in which case the first half is irrelevant).

Comment: ```for  i in /root/d/*.jpg; do``` - this construction will works incorrectly with files which could contains spaces. I think you need to write function or separate script and use find with ``exec myscript {} \;``

Comment: @AdminBee thanks  am confuse  about title

Comment: @Saboteur i add update 3 , please check

Comment: i set answer hope to forgive me , if i was not clear

Answer (score 1):

The main issues with your `convert` command is that the argument `$WIDTHx$HEIGHT\>` tries to expand a variable called `$WIDTHx`.  As this variable does not exist, the argument used with `-resize` will be just whatever `$HEIGHT\>` is (which is the same as using `"${HEIGHT}x$HEIGHT>"`). You fix this by using `-resize "${WIDTH}x$HEIGHT>"`.  This is an issue in both your `find` commands.

To shrink your too large images, you could possibly use something like

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

w=1280
h=720

find /home/*/public_html -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) \
    -exec convert -resize "${w}x${h}>" {} \;
```

Personally, I would just restore the images from the latest backup, as scaling images up and down like this is bound to reduce their quality drastically.

When testing things out, run on smaller sets of copies of your images before letting your scripts loose on your whole image collection. Also make sure that your backups are running as expected.

Comment: thanks but i need convert run only after check path of img and it's greater than 1280px

Comment: @MikelTawfik Could you possibly test my `find` command as it currently is, on a copy of a subset of images, to see if it does the right thing.  I'm sure it would be easy to adjust it if it seems to do the wrong thing.

Comment: convert: no images defined `/home/sen/tes/c73f3dfe4fbb7ccf149797e1644255b1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.
convert: no images defined `/home/sen/tes/wallpapersden.com_lily-aldridge-sexy-little-bride-wallpaper_3840x2160.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.

Comment: i fix code  by convert {}  -verbose  -resize "${w}x${h}>" {} \;   but. same problem , files modified date updated every time i run

Comment: @MikelTawfik You never said that updating timestamps were an issue.

Comment: at my Q.  but I was shocked today when I run

ls -l 
and found all photos modified, data changed, big or not

Comment: i add update 3 , please check

Answer (score -1):

am so sorry i was not clear , i found and build my final script
and hope to correct title of Q with clever one

script search for files `jpg` or `png` and if found
check Width if found  greater than 1280 will convert

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/sen/tes/  -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)   | while read i; do \
read -r w h <<<$(identify -format "%w %h" "$i")
if [ $w  ]; then
if [ $w -gt  1280 ]; then
FOLDER="$i"
WIDTH=1280
HEIGHT=720
find ${FOLDER}  -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \)    -exec convert \{} -verbose -resize ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}\> \{} \;
fi
fi
done
```